# Filter rows where all matching rows are True

Tags: filter, powerquery

I have a table formatted as follows:

| BOM | Imported |
| --- | --- |
| COM123 | True |
| COM123 | True |
| COM123 | False |
| COM999 | True |
| COM999 | True |
| COM999 | True |

I'd like to filter the table to show only rows where all matching BOM rows are True in the Imported column. I.e., in this case, COM999 rows should show, and COM123 rows are filtered out because one entry is False.

FYI this is to produce a list of Production BOMs where all the components already exist in Business Central. The Imported column is the result from a merge of the query with an extract from BC, and sets the value to true where the BOM components exist.

Can anyone please give me a steer?

I've been farting around with this half the day, but I can't find the equivalent to a EXISTS query in SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm should be clear in the code comments

- Group by BOM
- Test each BOM subgroup for ALLTRUE
- Filter the Grouped table
- Re-expand the original

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table21"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"BOM", type text}, {"Imported", type logical}}),
    
//Group rows by BOM
//Then determine where all "Imported" = True
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"BOM"}, {
        {"all true", each List.AllTrue([Imported]), type logical},
        {"all", each _, type table [BOM=nullable text, Imported=nullable logical]}}),

//Remove the false rows
//then delete the "all true" column
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([all true] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"all true"}),

//re-expand
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "all", {"Imported"}, {"Imported"})
in
    #"Expanded all"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron, that works really well, I've joined the result with the original table so I can filter the rows based on that :) Much appreciated!